# VPN to avoid the Great Firewall of China is only partly working

Tags: vpn, firewall, port, pptp

I have a PPTP VPN server and my friend from China has no trouble connecting to it, but he can't open any blocked website except Gmail (and sending mail doesn't work). Google DNS works fine, but it's not a DNS issue since pinging Google's IP (for example) results in a timeout. What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: The firewall is guessing the packet content from side channels - they identify that you're tunneling https. This was a good read for me on how to fight it: http://blog.zorinaq.com/my-experience-with-the-great-firewall-of-china/

Comment: Can you test your server first? Connect from another computer that's neither in your Lan nor in a 3rd-world country, then see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Marek Rost's comment appeared as I was writing my post. I read the link he gave, http://blog.zorinaq.com/my-experience-with-the-great-firewall-of-china/, after submitting my post. It is perfectly clear the GFW has reached a level of sophistication that surpasses by far that of my comments below. I will leave the post, in the hope of helping someone else, someone obviously not based in China. **Many thanks** to Marek Rost for pointing me to a most illuminating post.

Sorry about the ruckus.

---

It is difficult to evade the measures of a powerful state, with very few limits to its actions. Said state might, for instance, block all encrypted communications, irrespective of port, protocol and destinations. This would still allow ICMP packets (to Google, for instance) because in general these carry no content (but see below).

I would still like to suggest a few alternatives to try, even though I have never been to China, so I have no idea whatsoever whether they will work or not.

1. Do not use your standard DNS server, try using [DNSCrypt](https://dnscrypt.org/) instead. This is a free application which both uses a random port for DNS queries and encrypts them.
2. Use a non-standard port for your VPN. The safest thing would be to use OpenVPN, then experiment with ports and protocols (OpenVPN can use both TCP and UDP, albeit not simultaneously). Even commercial providers will give a long list of access points for different ports and/or protocols. You might strike lucky.
3. If all of the above fails, you may try an [ICMP tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_tunnel). This uses ICMP (=ping) protocol packets to setup a TCP connection between two distant machines. It occurred to me because you mentioned being able to ping Google. It has the advantage that blocking this, given that **some** packets do pass, requires inspection of every single packet, rather than just dumping all encrypted communications.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The PRC actively watches for people using Tor and VPNs.

I believe the answer is that they have figured out how to cause you trouble by blocking just a subset of the ports used by your VPN.

There might be a reason they don't totally block it - like it might affect things other than just your VPN